# Transferring Data Between Python and C++ Without Writing To File Windows and Unix

Tags: python, c++, linux, windows, unix

I have pre-existing python and C++ files where the python file defines a number of points and the C++ code does the calculations I need with its existing libraries. The end product of this is a file that the C++ code writes out. I am looking for a way in python to take a list of say 2000 points, pass it to a function and then all of the C++ code is executed and the file I need is output.

Some other notes. This needs to be something that could work on Linux or Windows machines, and a minimal amount of installing new plugins would be nice (but I will take what I can get). Also this is all going to be run on the same machine.

Please let me know what my best options are!

Comment: google://"python ffi"

Comment: Python provides a C-API, also you could consider to use `boost::python` for interfacing.

Comment: Requesting libraries, documentation, examples, tutorials is off-topic in SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can define message between python and C++ using google's protobuf:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

Define a .proto file following the protobuf convention, then convert that proto file to python package, and C++ definitions.

Add a message between python and C++ application, while sending the message make sure you encode and receiving decode it using proper APIs. Include the headers and package when compiling.

Answer (score 0):

this is possible, but you will have to take your time. some steps are needed.

you can use swig to make a shared library/dll that will wrap your c++ function for python. this will run on  linux / and windows, if you compile it for linux and win32.

Another option is to embed python in c++.

finally to package the whole thing for windows use cx_freeze to make a windows exe and  then innosetup to make an installation package.